# How can I convert pivot style data into list data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I essentially have data arrange like a pivot table in the blue table example and I would like to do a "reverse pivot" to have it formatted as is it in the green table. Its not an actual pivot table but its arranged in the same way. Optimally I would like to just use formulas but if its not possible, what would be the best method in VBA to achieve this? My actual data set is quite large (~350 rows by ~100 columns) and has to be updated constantly so it has to be completely automated. Any guidance is much appreciated!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epsGa.png)

I've tried a number of built in excel functions but I can't seem to find something that matches my case.

Comment: `=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",0,A2:A5&","&B1:F1&","&B2:F5),",",";")` would work on the example. Not sure if it works on a large dataset

Comment: I'd use Power Query and unpivot those columns.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have 2016 Excel and do not have access to those functions unfortunately!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered "Unpivot" in Excel PowerQuery, as [explained in this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)?

This only works if the table is not formatted as an Excel pivot table, otherwise you'll get an error "A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query results, protected cells, or another table."

Here's an example of data that was previously pivoted:

```
+--------+------+------+------+
|  SKU   |  1   |  7   |  8   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| 006101 | 0.87 | 0.87 | 0.87 |
| 006309 | 0.87 | 0.87 | 0.87 |
| 006507 | 0.87 | 0.87 | 0.87 |
| 006705 | 0.87 | 0.87 | 0.87 |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

After loading it into PowerQuery, you select the columns you want to unpivot, then go to "Transform" and select "Unpivot Columns" in the "Any Column" group. I picked columns 1, 7, 8.

This is the resulting M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyDataSource"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SKU", type text}, {"1", type number}, {"7", type number}, {"8", type number}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"SKU"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Attribute", "ST"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

And this is the resulting output when you load the data back into Excel (you can also just create a connection in PowerQuery, if you wish to process it further):

```
+--------+----+-------+
|  SKU   | ST | Value |
+--------+----+-------+
| 006101 |  1 |  0.87 |
| 006101 |  7 |  0.87 |
| 006101 |  8 |  0.87 |
| 006309 |  1 |  0.87 |
| 006309 |  7 |  0.87 |
| 006309 |  8 |  0.87 |
| 006507 |  1 |  0.87 |
| 006507 |  7 |  0.87 |
| 006507 |  8 |  0.87 |
| 006705 |  1 |  0.87 |
| 006705 |  7 |  0.87 |
| 006705 |  8 |  0.87 |
+--------+----+-------+
```

Comment: After posting this, I saw you stated you don't have access to PowerQuery. PowerQuery has been included in Excel since your version, which you say is 2016.  (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/09/10/integrating-power-query-technology-in-excel-2016/)

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad to hear you got it working!